# In Haskell how should I ignore if a number is Int or Integer?

Tags: haskell

In my homework I have to write a program which tells me if 2 numbers can be devided, BUT when there is the input sometimes the number are Ints and sometimes Integers.

I tried it with all a. Num => a but it didn't work either. I may have misstyped it

Comment: Please share your current attempt.

Comment: `Num a => a` is indeed normally the way to go for this, but just using this in the signature isn't always sufficient. Show some more of the code you have tried so we can analyse where it went wrong.

Answer (score 7):

**No**, you should use the [**`Integral`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) for *integral* numbers, where `Int` and `Integer` are members of the `Integral` typeclass.

The `Integral` typeclass provides functions like [**`quot :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:quot), [**`rem :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:rem), etc. which should make it possible to check for two integral numbers if one can be divided by the other.

So your function has signature:

```
isDividable :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
isDividable = …
```